# Access is denied when search external SharePoint site

Tags: search, external-data

We have an internet (SharePoint 2013) and intranet (SharePoint 2010).
I want to have our internet (`http://www.example.com`) items in our intranet search result. We also have proxy setting.

I created a web site content source and I typed `"http://www.example.com"` in "Type start addresses below (one per line):" but I got "Access is denied" error.

Comment: what you mean by search extranet site, is it crawling get access denied, did you content access acount has the read permission on example dot come?

Comment: it is an anonymous website, should I get permission to search account?

Comment: did you specify the anonymous authentication while setting up the crawl rule?

Comment: are you crawling from 2010 or from 2013 search?

Comment: I want to have 2013 result in 2010. our 2013 website is an anonymous site.

Comment: You should crawl from 2013 and then connect 2010 to the 2013 search service. It is significantly better. As indicated by others you can then use anonymous crawling.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 requires a **user account for crawling content** from sites, even if they are **configured for Anonymous authentication**.

SharePoint 2013 resolves this issue by introducing a new approach – Anonymous which eliminate the need of passing an user account and trying to authenticate for crawling content for public-facing web sites with anonymous authentication.

[Article anonymous crawl configuration in sharepoint 2013](http://www.sharepoint24x7.com/2014/07/09/article-anonymous-crawl-configuration-in-sharepoint-2013/)

**Alternate** to this is crawl that site as Web Sites instead of SharePoint site.

http://www.sharepointblues.com/2011/02/25/how-to-configure-crawl-for-anonymous-sharepoint-2010-site/

Comment: after following Alternate link adding crawl rule, I still getting "Access is denied"